unix.stackexchange.com redirects to https://www.citysearch.com/profile/13672866/?publisher=adnet
I thought you had this subdomain but you don't; was surprised where it redirected though. You might need to modify your server.

Unable to reproduce. Most likely it's something wrong with your network's DNS lookup. Try switching to another DNS resolver to see if this still happens for you (you may need to clear your browser's cache).

No repro here either. Perhaps needless to say, if it's not resolved that way, try running antivirus software to get rid of browser-hijack software or anything that redirects your browser. ... Try a different browser etc..

Using unix tools: dig @8.8.8.8 unix.stackexchange.com A gives me as IP address 104.18.43.226 and 172.64.144.30.  And curl -vvvv  https://unix.stackexchange.com/  returns me a 200 OK with an HTML payload that I expect. All linked JavaScript in that payload is pointing to servers under control by SE. There must be something between your browser and an SE server that redirects. Either your browser, device, active network devices, ISP, Upstream ISPs or maybe a local to your area CloudFlare server is acting up. This needs more diagnosing steps on your end.

Modifying SE server won't help your compromised device.


I thought you had this subdomain but you don't

The WHOIS database thinks otherwise
Domain Name: stackexchange.com
Registry Domain ID: 1558969914_DOMAIN_COM-VRSN
Registrar WHOIS Server: whois.corporatedomains.com
Registrar URL: www.cscprotectsbrands.com
Updated Date: 2024-06-08T01:13:57Z
Creation Date: 2009-06-12T09:55:30Z
Registrar Registration Expiration Date: 2025-06-12T13:55:30Z
...
Domain Status: clientTransferProhibited http://www.icann.org/epp#clientTransferProhibited
Registry Registrant ID:
Registrant Name: Sysadmin Team
Registrant Organization: Stack Exchange, Inc.
Registrant Street: 14 Wall Street, 20th Floor
Registrant City: New York
Registrant State/Province: NY
Registrant Postal Code: 10005-2123
Registrant Country: US
....
Admin Name: Sysadmin Team
Admin Organization: Stack Exchange, Inc.
Admin Street: 14 Wall Street, 20th Floor
Admin City: New York
Admin State/Province: NY
Admin Postal Code: 10005-2123
Admin Country: US
....
Registry Tech ID:
Tech Name: Sysadmin Team
Tech Organization: Stack Exchange, Inc.
...
Name Server: damian.ns.cloudflare.com
Name Server: sureena.ns.cloudflare.com

There is a slight concern by the updated date 2024-06-08T01:13:57Z but I assume that is only to reflect they paid for the domain for another year. The client transfer prohibited should prevent the domain can be transferred to a different owner on a whim.
When I run
dig @8.8.8.8 unix.stackexchange.com A 

it outputs  IP address 104.18.43.226 and 172.64.144.30 for me, today. (I'm in Western Europe, in case that matters)
And curl -vvvv  https://unix.stackexchange.com/ returns me a 200 OK with an HTML payload that I expect. All linked JavaScript in that payload is pointing to servers under control by SE.
There must be something between your browser and an SE server that responds with redirect HTTP payloads. Either your browser, device, active network devices, ISP, Upstream ISPs, VPN providers or maybe a local to your area CloudFlare server is acting up.
This needs more diagnosing steps and resolving of any found issues on your end.
There are examples of similar behavior happening in the past: the domain stackoverflow.com is for sale
And while back in 2015 stackoverflow.com was for sale we were reassured that the domains were not going to switch ownership soon. I assume that still holds for all domains today as long as the lights stay on, aka the bills are paid.

Glad to hear it. Yeah must be a problem on my end. OUch those downvotes

@SamuelMarks going forward you might first want to check with folks in chat when you experience an issue with an SE server. While downtime / misconfiguration does happen, it is rare for the SE infrastructure and services and when it does get noticed people often run to chat first to call it out. Added benefit is that chat doesn't have downvotes, so if you made the wrong call no rep is lost ;)

Ah I keep forgetting StackOverflow now has chat. Can you delete the question or something? - It's now -12; any more negative and my account will be banned I'm sure

On meta you have to do way worse to get banned.
